# Creating an iOS Local Notification

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When loading the sample code in Xamarin Studio, the app runs as expected.

[Xamarin.com Local Notifications Sample Code](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/LocalNotifications/)

But when starting a new single view project, I tried using bits of the code that seemed necessary.  The viewcontroller class is structured differently, than in the sample code, on a new project.

ViewController.cs

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;

namespace TestProject1
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {

        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        partial void ButButton_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
        {
            var notification = new UILocalNotification();
            notification.FireDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(5);
            notification.AlertAction = "Test";
            notification.AlertBody = "Test Text";
            notification.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
            notification.SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);

            //throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.cs

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        private ViewController viewController;
        private UIWindow window;

        public override UIWindow Window {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            viewController = new ViewController();
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            viewController = new ViewController ();
            window.RootViewController = viewController;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            //if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
                var notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (
                                               UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, null
                                           );
                application.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (notificationSettings);
            //}

            if (launchOptions != null)
            {
                // check for a local notification
                if (launchOptions.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey))
                {
                    var localNotification = launchOptions[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as UILocalNotification;
                    if (localNotification != null)
                    {
                        UIAlertController okayAlertController = UIAlertController.Create (localNotification.AlertAction, localNotification.AlertBody, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                        okayAlertController.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
                        viewController.PresentViewController (okayAlertController, true, null);

                        // reset our badge
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        public override void ReceivedLocalNotification(UIApplication application, UILocalNotification notification)
        {
            // show an alert
            UIAlertController okayAlertController = UIAlertController.Create (notification.AlertAction, notification.AlertBody, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okayAlertController.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            viewController.PresentViewController (okayAlertController, true, null);

            // reset our badge
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In the sample project, the only difference is ViewController is declared with no parameters: public ViewController { }.  If I add that code, the app complies and runs.  The notifications fires and shows the badge, but never shows appears within the app.

Instead of trying to rig the code on a new project, how do you properly declare: viewController = new ViewController(); with a IntPtr parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are adding ViewControllers through Storyboard, right ?

Comment: No, I was using the existing ViewController from the new project.  There is only one.

Comment: No Storyboard or XIB ?

Comment: It does have a StoryBoard.  No XIB on the controller.

Comment: View for the ViewController is in Storyboard right ?

Comment: Yes, when starting a new Single View project, a default ViewController is created and also a StoryBoard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111205/discussion-between-sreeraj-and-detailcode).

Comment: It appears as though I cannot even add a UI control during the FinishedLaunching() event.  However the ViewController is structured in ViewController.cs or declared in AppDelegate.cs, the code does not interact with the actual view once the app starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to use attach the alert to the ViewController as shown in the demo code, use UIAlertView.

```
public override void ReceivedLocalNotification(UIApplication application, UILocalNotification notification)
{
    UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView () { Title = notification.AlertAction, Message = notification.AlertBody };
    alert.AddButton("OK");
    alert.Show ();
    // CLEAR BADGES
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```